# Does the quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties property work in hibernate reactive?

Tags: quarkus

Does this option(quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties) work in hibernate reactive?
I need to add the option "hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer": "allow". To allow the service to merge identical objects in different entities in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

`quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties` is expected to work on the Quarkus extension for Hibernate Reactive, yes. Feel free to open an issue if you notice that a property is not propagated correctly to Hibernate Reactive.

I do not know if `hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer` works in Hibernate Reactive, though. In the scope of Quarkus, it is, well, unsupported.
You might want to [ask the Hibernate Reactive maintainers](https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user).